# RPi 4 not recognising M2 drive in argon case

Tags: raspbian, usb, pi4-eeprom

I have a raspberry pi 4b, which has been booting happily off an external usb-connected ssd. I have now put it into an Argon ONe case, with an MD SSD, and it will not recognise the M2 drive at all as a block device.

`lsusb -t` shows two mass storage devices on the usb interface:

```
/:  Bus 02.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/4p, 5000M
    |__ Port 1: Dev 2, If 0, Class=Mass Storage, Driver=uas, 5000M
    |__ Port 2: Dev 3, If 0, Class=Mass Storage, Driver=usb-storage, 5000M
```

Device 03 is the new drive.
Device 02 is the old drive, which works.

I can see from this that they have different drivers, and I suppose that must have something to do with the problem. But how can I solve it? Can I force the use of the uas driver, if that is the one that works?

Comment: Please do not add "SOLVED" to a question title.  After 24h, you should be able to green tick your own answer.  Please also take [the tour](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/tour) to understand better how the site works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved. It turns out the problem was — for once — insufficient force applied. I needed to shove the ssd into its slot so hard that it clicked, like a stick of ram. After that everything was fine.